# CRS defaults to WGS 84 on opening a project without OTF

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS 2.18.15, I open a project and my component shapefiles have migrated to the west coast of Africa. Here's what's leading up to this:

1. I've disabled OTF on startup since there are well-documented geometry calculation issues that arise with OTF enabled.
2. My default projection is set to EPSG 102710 (NAD 1983 State Plane New Hampshire US Feet). All component shapefiles are projected to this as well.
3. When trying to calculate acreage for various polygons, these calculations are wonky, thus:

   - The "output preview" for the expression $area / 43560 correctly displays acreage, and *yet*:
   - The calculated column in the attribute table returns a value that is 1/10.7639 of the actual value. There are 10.7639 square feet in a square meter.
4. When I add a new vector layer, the "selected CRS" always displays as WGS 84 and I must manually select EPSG 102710, even though this is set to the default.

So it seems QGIS is defaulting to WGS 84 and metric measurements. If I turn OTF off, my shapefiles return from the African Atlantic to their rightful places in New Hampshire.

I do have several QuickmapServices layers included in my project.

Happy to provide other info if needed.

Comment: Additionally, if I enter the Project Properties and turn on OTF, I can select EPSG 102710. If I then deselect OTF, the selected CRS jumps right back to WGS 84. Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

What have you set with your bullet 2). Is it the default CRS for new projects or the CRS for new layers?

[image]

Comment: I have "Use project CRS" selected. The project CRS default is set to 102710; shouldn't the second and third choices then do the same thing?

Comment: Perhaps yes but it is rather cheap to have a try with Use default CRS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - didn't seem to do much though.

Comment: I suggest to use `Prompt for CRS` to avoid any unwanted results.